# Prove that $\text{aff}(X) = \text{aff}(\text{closure}(X))$

Tags: convex-analysis

I am trying to prove that the affine hull of a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ is equal to the affine hull of the clojure of that set: $$
\text{aff}(X) = \text{aff}(\text{cl}(X)).
$$

Proving $\text{aff}(X) \subseteq \text{aff}(\text{cl}(X))$ is easy, but containment in the other direction is harder.

I am assuming there is a sequence $\{ x_k \}_{k=1}^\infty \subseteq X$ such that $\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k = x^*$. The point $x^*$ is obviously contained in $\text{aff}(\text{cl}(X))$. But I am not sure how to show it is also in $\text{aff}(X)$, specifically because I am not sure how to show that $x^*$ lies on a line connecting two points in $X$.

Any suggestions on how to surmount this hurdle are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is closed, in particular the intersection of all subspaces containing $X$. Therefore $\text{Aff}(X)$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ containing $X$, hence also $\text{Closure}(X)$. Because $\text{Aff}(X)$ is the smallest affine subspace containing $X$, it is also the smallest  affine subspace containing Closure($X$). 
 
**Edit:** Let us prove that every affine subspace $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is closed. Pick $a \in A$ and set $W = -a +A$. It is clear that $A$ is closed if and only if $W$ is closed. Next, we wishes to write $W$ as the solution set to some finite set of equations, from which we can conclude that it is closed. For this, choose a basis $\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$ of $W$. Next, write
$$ w_i = \sum_{k=1}^d w_i(k) e_k, $$
and 
$$ x = \sum_{k=1}^d x_k e_k, $$
where $e_1,\ldots,e_d$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

Then an element $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ satisfies $x \in W$ if and only if there exist $\lambda_1,\ldots, \lambda_n \in \mathbb{R}$ such that 
$$ x= \lambda_1 w_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n w_n. $$
This is equivalent to
$$ \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_d \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  w_1(1) &\cdots & w_n(1) \\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
w_1(d) &\cdots & w_n(d)
 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n \end{pmatrix}. $$
Because the rank of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}  w_1(1) &\cdots & w_n(1) \\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
w_1(d) &\cdots & w_n(d)
 \end{pmatrix} $ is $n \leq d$, Gaussian elimination will let you write this as
$$A \begin{pmatrix}  x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_d 
 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}  \lambda_1 \\ \vdots \\ \lambda_n
 \end{pmatrix} $$
for some matrix $A \in M^{n \times d}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $W = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $f$ is the continuous funcion $\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n: x \mapsto Ax$.

Comment: Thanks, I guess my issue then is how to prove that an affine subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is closed. I suppose I could prove its complement is open. But that seems less aesthetically satisfying than proving closedness directly.

Comment: See my edit, any affine set can be written as the solution set of some finite set of equations. These can be written in a matrix-model. Then, can you finish the argument by yourself by the following idea: if $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(K)$ is closed whenever $K$ is closed?

Comment: Apologies for being dim here, but is the continuous function you are talking about $f(x) \triangleq W x$?

Comment: No problem, but $f$ is not given by that definition. But I have added the construction of $f$ to my answer. Hope this helps. Alternatively, can you see that the subspace $\mathbb{R}^n \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is closed? If yes, then it follows that all subspaces of dimension $n$ are closed because they are all linear transforms of one another. These linear transforms map open sets to open.

Comment: Okay, thanks perfect.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{aff} X \subset \operatorname{aff} \overline{X} $. This is always true.

In finite dimensional spaces, $\operatorname{aff} X$ is closed and hence 
$\overline{X} \subset \operatorname{aff} X$. Hence
$\operatorname{aff} \overline{X} \subset \operatorname{aff}(\operatorname{aff} X ) = \operatorname{aff} X $.